# On IServiceProvider what are the differences between the GetRequiredService and GetService methods?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

What are the differences between `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService()` and `IServiceProvider.GetService()`?

When is it a better idea to use `GetRequiredService()`?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You should rarely have to call these methods at all, as you should use constructor injection where ever possible.

In rare cases, such as factories or to dynamically instantiate command handlers, you can resolve it yourself.

That being said, you should use `GetRequiredService` where you **require** the service. It will throw an exception, when the service is not registered.

`GetService` on the other side is for **optional** dependencies, which will just return `null` when there is no such service registered.

Comment: You should note that if you are using an external DI provider, this semantics can change a little, for example, in StructureMap both functions behave different: https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/37

Answer (score 80):

The difference is that `GetService<T>()` returns `null` if it can't find the service. `GetRequiredService<T>()` throws an `InvalidOperationException` instead.